# How to remove menu in windows 7 folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Folders in Win7 have menu with commands "Organize", "Include in library", "Share with", "Burn", "New folder". How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove some of them editing the registry
   Run regedit to open the Registry Editor and navigate to the following key:
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

remove the ones you dont want, be careful not to remove something else 
or you may want to try some of the free "Context Menu Editors" google for them and you will get at least 4 popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following link could help you.

How to Auto-Hide or Disable Command Bar in Windows Vista and 7 Explorer?
https://www.askvg.com/how-to-make-folder-band-auto-hidden-in-windows-vista/